# Порядок вывода переменных

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему выполняя данный код:

```js
let year = new Date().getFullYear()
let month = new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long'});
const daysOfWeek = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс']

document.write(`<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7" >${month}` + ' ' + `${year}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ${daysOfWeek.join(' ')}
    </tr>
</table>`)
```

первым выводится массив, который указан после переменных ${month} и ${year} ?
Результат работы кода:
Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб Вс
октябрь 2020

Comment: вы ячейку забыли закрыть и верстка "утекла"

Answer (score 0):

Потому что дни недели не попали ни в какую ячейку таблицы.

```js
let year = new Date().getFullYear()
let month = new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long'});
const daysOfWeek = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс']

document.write(`<table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="7" >${month}` + ' ' + `${year}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>${daysOfWeek.join(' ')}</td>
    </tr>
</table>`)
```